# new plane equation after transformation of coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

I have a plane equation $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ w.r.t to a particular coordinate frame. 
this coordinate frame w.r.t to the world coordinate frame is

$$\begin{vmatrix}
  r_1 & r_2 & r_3 & x_1 \\
  r_4 & r_5 & r_6 & y_1 \\
  r_7 & r_8 & r_9 & z_1 
\end{vmatrix}$$

now, what is the equation of plane in the world coordinate frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of the plane can be created from the dot product of two homogeneous vectors

$$ ax+by+cz+d = 0$$
$$ \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\\1 \end{pmatrix}^\intercal \begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{pmatrix} =0 $$

The world coordinates of the local $(x,y,z,1)$ are

$$ \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ w \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  = 
\begin{vmatrix}
  r_1 & r_2 & r_3 & x_1 \\
  r_4 & r_5 & r_6 & y_1 \\
  r_7 & r_8 & r_9 & z_1 \\
   0 &   0  &  0  &  1 
\end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Taking the inverse you find that the coefficients $(A,B,C,D)$ of the plane $Au+Bv+Cw+D=0$ are

$$ \begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \\ C\\ D \end{pmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
  r_1 & r_2 & r_3 & x_1 \\
  r_4 & r_5 & r_6 & y_1 \\
  r_7 & r_8 & r_9 & z_1 \\
   0 &   0  &  0  &  1 
\end{vmatrix}^{-\intercal} \begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: taking the inverse only? or inverse and then transform of it?

Comment: $\mbox{ }^{-\intercal}$ is the inverse-transpose operator. Inverse and then transpose. Note that: $$\begin{bmatrix} R & \vec{t} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-\intercal} = \begin{bmatrix} R & 0 \\ -\vec{t}^\intercal R & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ since $R^{-1} = R^\intercal$